# Is it possible to write list functions on the simply typed lambda calculus?

Tags: haskell, type-systems

Can you write polymorphic list functions such as `cons`, `nil` and `reverse` on the STLC?

To elaborate the question, in order to write `cons`, in Haskell, you need polymorphic types:

```
cons : ∀ a . a -> List a -> List a
```

There is no such thing as `∀` on the STLC, so I'd think it is obvious that polymorphic list functions are impossible, i.e., you need to write a new definition of `cons` for each specialized list type. But what if you leave the type annotation out, and instead have this:

```
cons = ...
a = cons 1 []
b = cons "" []
```

The inferencer can identify that `cons : Int -> List Int -> List Int` on the first case, and `cons : String -> List String -> List String` on the second case - no `forall` needed. Under this point of view, looks like polymorphic list functions aren't a problem on the STLC - you just can't annotate their types.

Comment: You at least need `let`-polymorphism for this to work.  In STLC every expression still does have a type, even if the particular language doesn't require you to write it.

Comment: The simply-typed lambda calculus is an explicitly typed language; the types are part of the syntax.

Comment: I think this is possible, but it could only produce lists of fixed (ie, in the type) size: `λ a:α. λ b:β. λ f:α->β->γ. f a b`

Comment: In STLC you can't even have types of the form `List Int`, i.e. parametric types. Adding this corresponds to weak-λω in Barendregt's "lambda cube"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to write polymorphic functions on STLC. In the definition of STLC there's no universally quantified types. In order to represent polymorphic lists you need some language with type abstraction, like System F.

In your question you mixed (please correct me, if I understand it wrong) the STLC with an inference algorithm for it. If you want polymorphic types, you need a language with type abstraction and application (in order to have type instantiation).

Type inference algorithms (like the ones used by Haskell or ML) consider a restrict version of System F, that is usually called Mini (or Core) ML. Such restrictions are motivated by the undecidability of type inference and checking for System F (details [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007298000475)). More details about this can be found on:

- Chapter 23 of Types and programming languages
- [A simple applicative language: Mini-ML](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076025/file/RR-0529.pdf). This article presents the language Mini-ML: its syntax, semantics, type system and type-inference algorithm. It's old, but very readable.
- [Practical type inference for arbitrary rank types](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/putting.pdf) presents a more expressive fragment of System F and discuss its implementation in Haskell.

Comment: Type checking is undecidable only for Curry-style System F (no explicit types at all). For Church-style System F (explicit type annotations in the appropriate places) type checking is decidable.